# Difference between /$ and ~$

Tags: ubuntu, directory, ls, home

When I log into a server running Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64 and run `ls` nothing shows and there is a ~$ at the end of the command prompt. When I type `cd /` the prompt changes to /$ and I can see many more directories listed. When I login am I initially in the home directory of the user and then by using `cd /` am I changing to the root directory of the system?

Comment: Yes 100% correct, and `~` is short-hand for your home directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct. You are in the user's home directory when you see `~$` and the "top level" or "root" directory when you see `/$`. Use `pwd` to "print working directory". This will show you the results of the two different paths.
A trick to get back to your default home directory `~$` is to simply type `cd` and press enter.

Comment: Consider a `touch myfile` in your home directory if it helps orient you.

Comment: And that `$` is part of your shell's prompt.

Comment: The user I'm logged in as has root privileges. If I was logged in as a user without these privileges would I be able to get to the "root" directory? Or is this just the users root directory.(Not sure if this is even a thing)

Comment: Yes you can go to the root directory as anyone, but you will not be able to write/change/create any files there. There are many files that you need to be able to read e.g. `ls` is in `/usr/bin/ls`. Also if you operate as root user (even if you know what you are doing) you will mess up, and break something. Add a new user, and use that. Then use `sudo` to gain privileges when you need them.

Comment: Thank you @ctrl-alt-delor that makes sense.